# Using kafka as messaging queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to use Kafka as a messaging queue in my controller (so task):

```
@RequestMapping("users")
@RestController
public class UserController extends BaseController {

    private static final String KAFKA_TOPIC = "virto_users";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> mKafkaTemplate;

    @PutMapping(value = "{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> put(@PathVariable UUID id,
                                      @RequestBody String profile) {
        String url = ServerConfig.USERS_HOST + "/users/" + id;
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = request.put(url, profile);
        HttpStatus status = entity.getStatusCode();

        if (status == HttpStatus.CREATED || status == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
            return entity;
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("id", id);
        json.put("profile", profile);
        sendMessage(json.toString());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        mKafkaTemplate.send(KAFKA_TOPIC, msg);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = KAFKA_TOPIC, groupId = KafkaConfig.GROUP_ID)
    public void listen(String message) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
        UUID id = UUID.fromString(json.getString("id"));
        String profile = json.getString("profile");
        put(id, profile);
    }
}
```

If my inner service is available and returned CREATED or NO_CONTENT then all is right and I can return result else I need to return the NO_CONTENT status and put this message in my queue to try again until it will be processed. I made it like above but it doesn't look like a good solution, imho. I wanted to ask just for a some advice how can I improve this solution or that it's normal.

Comment: Are you asking about the overall architecture or do you want specific advice on only the Kafka part?

Comment: I just wanted to hear an opinion whether my solution has rights for life

Comment: Well if you want a queueing system then use of Kafka in this scenario is well justified. It also depends upon the traffic that your system is handling because you will be assigning your infrastructure resources to the Kafka cluster too.